# How to add a semi-transparent background to a card's image overlay

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figoure out how to create an effect like this using Bootstrap's Card with Overlay:

[image]

Notice the opaque background of the text - my overlay always seems to cover the entire card's image.

```
<div class="row cols-flex">
  <div class="col">

    <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img src="assets/images/bp/road.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
      <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column align-items-start overlay">

        <p class="card-text mt-auto">Check out cool stuff</p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of `.card-img-overlay` built-it style

```
.card-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1.25rem;
    border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
}
```

Here, setting top and bottom to zero will result in your div being resized to width and height of the parent container. You can fix this by setting `top: inherit;` to `.overlay`.

Apart from that, `opacity: 0` results in fully transparent block. Use `opacity: 0.5` instead.

I made some changes to your code, here is the result
https://codepen.io/itdaos/pen/OJNQLxR

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to itdaos answer I found a solution by using his example as mentionned in his answer and by only using Bootstrap 5 :

```
<p class="card-text mt-auto position-absolute bottom-0 start-0 end-0 bg-black opacity-50">Check out cool stuff</p>
```